Create a new variable based on non-existing values on another variable in R dataframe
I know the title sounds very basic but I didn't find a solution by searching.
I have a dataframe like this where id refers to a participant:
id  condition
1   0 
1   0
1   1
1   2
2   0
2   0
2   1 
3   0

Now, some participants have failed to provide any observations for condition "2", and I'd like to create a new variable indicating whether the participant has any "2" responses vs. not. So the result should be
id  condition  cond2
1   0          yes
1   0          yes
1   1          yes
1   2          yes
2   0          no
2   0          no
2   1          no
3   0          no

is there an easy way for this? Thank you in advance!

Good question. Often it is better to use binary 1-0 or TRUE-FALSE (boolean) instead of chracters like yes-no. Also it makes code short: transform(df0, cond2 = ave(condition, id, FUN =\(x) any(x==2))), where df0 is a place holder for your data object.

Data
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), condition = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

Tidyverse
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(cond2 = if_else(any(condition == 2), "yes", "no"), .by = id)

#   id condition cond2
# 1  1         0   yes
# 2  1         0   yes
# 3  1         1   yes
# 4  1         2   yes
# 5  2         0    no
# 6  2         0    no
# 7  2         1    no
# 8  3         0    no

Base R
df$cond2 <- ave(df$condition, df$id, FUN = function(x) ifelse(any(x == 2), "yes", "no"))

df
#   id condition cond2
# 1  1         0   yes
# 2  1         0   yes
# 3  1         1   yes
# 4  1         2   yes
# 5  2         0    no
# 6  2         0    no
# 7  2         1    no
# 8  3         0    no


Here is another trick with merge + aggregate
> merge(df, aggregate(cbind(cond2 = c("no", "yes")[1 + (condition == 2)]) ~ id, df, max))
  id condition cond2
1  1         0   yes
2  1         0   yes
3  1         1   yes
4  1         2   yes
5  2         0    no
6  2         0    no
7  2         1    no
8  3         0    no

or a more straightforward and efficient option by ave
> transform(df, cond2 = c("no", "yes")[1 + (ave(condition == 2, id) > 0)])
  id condition cond2
1  1         0   yes
2  1         0   yes
3  1         1   yes
4  1         2   yes
5  2         0    no
6  2         0    no
7  2         1    no
8  3         0    no

